# How can I receive SignalR hub messages in Swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, signalr, swashbuckle, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

net 6.0 Web API app with SignalR, and I found a tool which helps me send signalR requests from Swagger, but I can't receive Socket response in swagger. Can you please tell me how can I do that.(I asked for owners of this package and they said that this package doesn't support this feature)
Package URL : https://github.com/essencebit/SignalRSwaggerGen/wiki

```
`    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSignalR(options =>
            {
                options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
            });
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "Game", Version = "v1" });
                c.AddSignalRSwaggerGen(ssgOption => ssgOption.HubPathFunc = (hubPath) => "/game");
            });

        }    `


`    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapHub<GameHub>("/game", config =>
                {
                    config.Transports = HttpTransportType.WebSockets;

                });
            });

 app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl($"https://{context.Request.Host.Value}/game{context.Request.QueryString}").WithAutomaticReconnect().Build();
                await hubConnection.StartAsync();
            });   `
```

I want to receive signalR responses in swagger